# ParameterError : data must be floating-point (librosa)

Tags: audio, speech-recognition, speech, librosa

Refernce : https://github.com/librosa/librosa/blob/master/examples/LibROSA%20demo.ipynb

**Code :**

```
import librosa

S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(samples, sr=sample_rate, n_mels=128)

log_S = librosa.power_to_db(S, ref=np.max)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))

librosa.display.specshow(log_S, sr=sample_rate, x_axis='time', y_axis='mel')

plt.title('mel power spectrogram')

plt.colorbar(format='%+02.0f dB')

plt.tight_layout()
```

**Erorr I am getting :**

[image: Error i am getting]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The parameter -- > **samples** in below method is not correct.

```
S = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(samples, sr=sample_rate, n_mels=128)
```

We are getting samples from wavfile read.

`sample_rate, samples = wavfile.read(str(train_audio_path) + filename)`

problem is specified in here [wave file read wrong](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/694)

So use the following line of code for getting **samples** in correct dtype.

```
samples, sample_rate = librosa.load(str(train_audio_path)+filename)
```

Reference : [librosa.github.io](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.feature.melspectrogram.html)

Comment: you are one hero